# ng-packagr Unable to publish the Angular package to npm OR how to Fix Angular Valunerablities

Tags: angular, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am facing this error while publish the package to the npm using the npm publish command:

> error code E403
> error 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/dist - You do not have permission to publish "dist". Are you logged in as the correct user?
> error 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> error 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
> verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0):

> Step-1: Add "resolutions" this section in your package.json file with the with the recommended package version.

```
"resolutions": {
    "postcss": "8.2.10",
    "node-fetch": "2.6.1"
  }
```

> Step-2: Run this command to remove the node_module

```
rm -r node_modules
```

> Step-3: Update the package-lock.json file by running this command

```
npx npm-force-resolutions
```

> Step-4: after this command run npm install commands to install all the required packages with updated versions.

```
npm install
```

> After the completion of all these steps now you can create the package again and publish to the npm. It works for me and I hopefully It works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unique package name. since this error is happened the package name you create is taken by others or something not allowed name.